# css code-duplication sophistically with LESS (or sass)

Tags: css, sass, less, code-duplication

I have this (a green button):

```
.btn_green_circle { width:13px; height:13px; position:relative; border-radius:7px; border:1px solid transparent;
    &:after { content:' '; width:9px; height:9px; background-color:#50B848; position:absolute; top:1px; left:1px; border-radius:5px; filter:alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; display:block; }
    &.active, &:hover { border:1px solid #C8C8C9;
        &:after { filter:alpha(opacity=100); opacity:1; }
    }
}
```

I want to do the same button but red (I can't use an extra class like: .btn.red_circle) so I need to write the same code again but with the background color changed.
(I could do it like - common styling:

```
 .btn_green_circle, .btn_red_circle { ... }
```

but was wondering if)

Is there is a more sophistically way of doing this with LESS or SASS?
(like with some mixin or something like that)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a mixin :

```
.btn_circle (@color) { 
    /*existing code*/

    background-color:@color;

    /*existing code*/
}

.btn_green_circle { 
    .btn_circle(#50B848); 
}

.btn_red_circle { 
    .btn_circle(#ff0000); 
}
```

Comment: @Symba That shouldn't be a problem, the mixin parameter will be available inside the nested rules. Just use your existing code, but replace the value by the parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You can pack all the properties of your button (that you already defined in your rule) into a mixin ... and adjust all the parameters you wan't to change between the buttons (like color in your case).

### In LESS:

```
.button(@color){
    width:13px; height:13px; position:relative; border-radius:7px; border:1px solid transparent;
    &:after { content:' '; width:9px; height:9px; background-color:@color; position:absolute; top:1px; left:1px; border-radius:5px; filter:alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; display:block; }
    &.active, &:hover { border:1px solid #c8c8c9;
        &:after { filter:alpha(opacity=100); opacity:1; }
    }
}
```

*(note - you can also use color functions and calculations in the mixin, to achieve multiple shades of the color passed in the mixin parameter if desired)*

then you simply call the mixin and pass desired parameters (your `#50B848` color or as in this example I do with `red`):

```
.btn_red_circle { 
  .button(red);
}
```

the same thing

### in Sass:

```
@mixin button($color) {
    width:13px; height:13px; position:relative; border-radius:7px; border:1px solid transparent;
    &:after { content:' '; width:9px; height:9px; background-color: $color; position:absolute; top:1px; left:1px; border-radius:5px; filter:alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; display:block; }
    &.active, &:hover { border:1px solid #c8c8c9;
        &:after { filter:alpha(opacity=100); opacity:1; }
    }
}

.btn_red_circle { 
  @include button(red);
}
```

In both LESS and Sass the **CSS** output will correspond to:

```
.btn_red_circle {
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.btn_red_circle:after {
  content: ' ';
  width: 9px;
  height: 9px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  opacity: 0.7;
  display: block;
}
.btn_red_circle.active,
.btn_red_circle:hover {
  border: 1px solid #c8c8c9;
}
.btn_red_circle.active:after,
.btn_red_circle:hover:after {
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
```